# php - header file - relative paths problem

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path, header-files

I have a web application in php. I have a `header.php` file where I have the opening html tag, meta data, css,js file includes.

I have multiple folders in this application. I have given relative paths to the css,js files in the `header.php`. The problem I am facing is, when I include this `header.php` file in some other file say, `./test-folder/my-file.php`, the relative paths break.

so to solve this i have given absolute paths where ever needed. But I have to change these paths every time I upload on to server. Can this be done in any other way?

Thanks in advance

Anji

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use static value for path instead define a constant for document root and use that constant

```
define('ROOT_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

While including files you can use this constant.

```
include ROOT_PATH.'/some_dir/file.php';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So in which file i need to define the `ROOT_PATH`? `header.php` will do?

Comment: @Anji: You should have one `config` file which will hold configuration variables and will be included as soon as your application initiate.

Comment: wont that be the same problem including `config` file?

Comment: @anji: No, That could not be you place your `config` file in document_root directory and can include directly like `include 'config.php'` The include of config file should be in your root `index.php` file

Answer (score 2):

You have bad architecture in your application. Try to search info about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).
This answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721353/what-is-good-neat-architecture-in-programming/5793753#5793753
So:

- change architicture,
- use [autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441686/how-to-autoload-extended-classes/1441792#1441792)

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory (cwd). If you just *include* another file that cwd does *not* change.
If you want to have paths that are (somewhat) relative to the current script file path you can use e.g.

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/some_dir/file.php';
```

or as of php 5.3

```
require __DIR__.'/some_dir/file.php';
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/language.constants.predefined

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you just would like to know the root folder your application without the need to hardcode it.

The easier way is to define a constant as Shakti has answered.

However, you could actually have a file with a unique name such as "foobar" in the root folder, then walk up the tree from current directory until you find foobar.

Comment: sorry I could not get what "foobar" file is about.

Comment: Say you have "foobar" in /var/www/public_html/, and your cwd is unknown, but surely something like /var/www/public_html/my/current/folder/.

After you got your current working directory, while foobar is not found go up one level. You got your root directory, when you found your foobar file.

Comment: yeah.. so basically foobar is used to get the root directory. thanks